# How To Make XMI file (or any standard code to make XMI file?)

Tags: xml, uml, xmi

I need help please, I'm beginner at programming, I want to make XMI file if there are any codes to make it and where i can make it,or it just a same when you make XML code?
And if there is no code to make XMI File then, in which application I can convert to XMI? and what kind of type file that the application can convert into XMI file? Thank you so much, i hope i got the answer tonight.

Comment: What are you looking for? The specs? Then for what will you create XMI and in which format? Have you visited OMG?

Comment: Serious [UML tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) support XMI import/export

Comment: I feel like the others that generating by "hand" an XMI file is a painfull and useless task. You can generate xmi files by coding but most of tools get a feature of reverse enegineering and as xmojmr said most of tools get a feature of XMI export. Some tools like papyrus store model as XMI file direclly. But Why do you want to generate an XMI file ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your questions correctly you are wanting to create your own XML files. For starting out, I would recommend downloading Notepad++ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.1.html). This is a text editor which you can set the language to XML in. To do so, you will select "language" at the top of your notepad and certain keywords/functions will be color-coded which helps make sense of your work.[I've attached a screenshot to show you how to do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzV2h.png)

As for "making an XML file" you can save plain text files (file type is .txt) by specifying .xml when you are using the Save As function. This can be done with the file type drop-down menu next to the save button. If you are using Notepad++ and specified XML as the language as above, then your file will automatically be saved as XML instead of just plain text.

Comment: Unless you are a masochist creating XMI in Notepad++ (or any other text editor) is simply a Sisyphus Labor.